# Conan : Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Protobuf"

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, conan

I've been trying now to install grpc (C++) via bazel and cmake.. both have failures.. BUT i thought to myself give conan a try.. but there's an error about `protobuf`.. so I added it to the requirements and yet it's not helping.. any ideas?

**Conanfile.py**

```
from conans import ConanFile, CMake, tools

GRPC_VERSION = "v1.48.0"

class GRPCExample(ConanFile):
    name = "grpc-example"
    version = GRPC_VERSION
    url = "https://github.com/grpc/grpc"
    description = "Built from grpcs example code in Github"
    topics = ("grpc", "example")
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    options = {"shared": [True, False]}
    default_options = {"shared": False}
    generators = "cmake"

    requires = [("protobuf/3.21.4")]

    def source(self):
        self.run("git clone --depth 1 --branch " + GRPC_VERSION + " https://github.com/grpc/grpc")

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure(source_folder="grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld")
        cmake.build()

    def package(self):
        self.copy("*.h", dst="include", src="grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld")
        self.copy("*.lib", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
        self.copy("*.dll", dst="bin", keep_path=False)
        self.copy("*.so", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
        self.copy("*.dylib", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
        self.copy("*.a", dst="lib", keep_path=False)

    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.libs = ["grpc-example"]
```

```
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
CMake Error at /home/emcp/.conan/data/grpc-example/v1.48.0/stonks/dev/build/1df012f840559ffd3600baf4353bf1a2db1635ac/grpc/examples/cpp/cmake/common.cmake:101 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Protobuf" with any
  of the following names:

    ProtobufConfig.cmake
    protobuf-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Protobuf" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Protobuf_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Protobuf" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:24 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/emcp/.conan/data/grpc-example/v1.48.0/stonks/dev/build/1df012f840559ffd3600baf4353bf1a2db1635ac/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
grpc-example/v1.48.0@stonks/dev: 
grpc-example/v1.48.0@stonks/dev: ERROR: Package '1df012f840559ffd3600baf4353bf1a2db1635ac' build failed
grpc-example/v1.48.0@stonks/dev: WARN: Build folder /home/emcp/.conan/data/grpc-example/v1.48.0/stonks/dev/build/1df012f840559ffd3600baf4353bf1a2db1635ac
ERROR: grpc-example/v1.48.0@stonks/dev: Error in build() method, line 25
        cmake.configure(source_folder="grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld")
        ConanException: Error 1 while executing cd '/home/emcp/.conan/data/grpc-example/v1.48.0/stonks/dev/build/1df012f840559ffd3600baf4353bf1a2db1635ac' && cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" -DCONAN_IN_LOCAL_CACHE="ON" -DCONAN_COMPILER="gcc" -DCONAN_COMPILER_VERSION="11" -DCONAN_CXX_FLAGS="-m64" -DCONAN_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="-m64" -DCONAN_C_FLAGS="-m64" -DCONAN_LIBCXX="libstdc++11" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS="OFF" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/home/emcp/.conan/data/grpc-example/v1.48.0/stonks/dev/package/1df012f840559ffd3600baf4353bf1a2db1635ac" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR="bin" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_SBINDIR="bin" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBEXECDIR="bin" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR="lib" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR="include" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_OLDINCLUDEDIR="include" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR="share" -DCMAKE_EXPORT_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY="ON" -DCONAN_EXPORTED="1" -Wno-dev '/home/emcp/.conan/data/grpc-example/v1.48.0/stonks/dev/build/1df012f840559ffd3600baf4353bf1a2db1635ac/grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld'
```

Comment: The ``cmake`` generator is not transparent. You need to add the ``include(.../conanbuildinfo.cmake)`` to your CMakeLists.txt, and also add the Conan targets to your own ones with ``target_link_libraries``. If you want the transparent integration with ``find_package()`` you need to use ``CMakeToolchain`` and ``CMakeDeps`` integration an pass it with ``cmake .... -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=.../conan_toolchain.cmake``

Comment: Also, if you use the modern transparent integration, do not use ``from conans import CMake`` which is legacy, but ``from conan.tools.cmake import CMake`` one.

Comment: @drodri is this what you're talking about ? https://blog.conan.io/2021/10/19/New-CMake-Transparent-Integration-Guide.html  If so I will def. rewrite all my conanfiles.py

Comment: also, the project is external to me so.. I cannot modify the `CMakeLists.txt` within the repo.. I guess I will need to do it inline via conan

Comment: Yes, also in the docs: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/tools/cmake.html. If you cannot modify the CMakeLists, then even with more reason you need to use these new tools